# invoke click on a buton in UWP webview on HTML DOM without an id

Tags: c#, html, dom, uwp

I have c# UWP app and I want to click a button with HTML DOM shown below using a webview.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-extra-pad btn-shadow" onclick="checkMsgShowBig()">Send</button>
```

Normally an **input** has a **id**, and the code below does the trick

```
var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementById('id').click();");
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

But the button only has a class name.
The code below should work when using a class name, but it does not work.

```
var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('id').click();");
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

How do I make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from `getElementsByClassName` is an array so you should index it before using it.

Here is a code sample

```
private async void SimulateClickAsync()
{
    var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary btn-extra-pad btn-shadow')[0].click();");
    await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working now. Just to understand, if I have 5 buttons with the same class names, does the _index_ value represent a specific button or do we always index with a 0?

Comment: @Zee No. Different index represents different button.